# PHP preg_replace with addslashes to string that may or may not contain comma quoted values

Tags: php, regex

**Background..**

This is user input being collected so I need to expect some strange stuff and try to fix up string before passing these into functions. User input is stored into the database similar to so:

```
{"value":"O'Neil,'Smith',\"O'Reilly\",100"}
```

So the script pulls these out of the database, json_decodes them, and then now I'm trying to fix those value strings up. Here's the best example of that I can give.

```
$json = '{"value":"O\'Neil,\'Smith\',\"O\'Reilly\",100"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

**The Goal..**

How could I go about escaping quotes in strings like so:

```
O'Neil,Smith,O'Reilly,100
"O'Neil","Smith","O'Reilly",100
'O'Neil','Smith','O'Reilly',100
O'Neil,'Smith',"O'Reilly",100
```

So that I get the following result out of each:

```
'O\'Neil','Smith','O\'Reilly',100
```

Values may or may not contain commas. It could just be a single value like `O'Neil` or `100`.

I'm pretty sure preg_replace could so something like this, or even preg_replace_callback, but I'm just not sure how to go about this.

The below do not work at all but I'm thinking one of these approaches should work.

```
$value = preg_replace('/(.*?)/', '$1', $array['value']);
$value = preg_replace_callback('/(.*?)/', 'addslashes', $array['value']);
```

I've also tried exploding the strings using the commas and looping the values but that escapes the quotes I don't want to touch as well.

Thanks all!

Comment: Might you get commas in the words themselves, or are they always the delimiters?

Comment: There could be but I don't think I'm too worried about those. They should just be left alone if within quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this function will do what you want. It uses `preg_match_all` to find either a quoted string (single or double, possibly with escaped quotes inside), or a set of non-comma characters. Each of those values is then trimmed of quotes, and any non-escaped single quotes are replaced with escaped ones. Finally non-numeric values are placed into single quotes:

```
function quote($value) {
    preg_match_all('/"(?:\\\\"|[^"])*"|\'(?:\\\\\'|[^\'])*\'|[^,]+/', $value, $values);
    foreach ($values[0] as &$value) {
        $value = trim($value, "'\"");
        $value = preg_replace("/(?<!\\\\)'/", "\\'", $value);
        if (!is_numeric($value)) $value = "'$value'";
    }
    return implode(',', $values[0]);
}
```

To use with your sample strings:

```
echo quote("O'Neil,Smith,O'Reilly,100") . PHP_EOL;
echo quote("\"O'Neil\",\"Smith\",\"O'Reilly\",100") . PHP_EOL;
echo quote("'O\'Neil','Smith','O\'Reilly',100") . PHP_EOL;
echo quote("O'Neil,'Smith',\"O'Reilly\",100") . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
'O\'Neil','Smith','O\'Reilly',100
'O\'Neil','Smith','O\'Reilly',100
'O\'Neil','Smith','O\'Reilly',100
'O\'Neil','Smith','O\'Reilly',100
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/1abI9i)

Comment: Well hot damn! This sure was exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly. Thank you so very much Nick!

Comment: I'm a little curious myself. Explanation please?